# Convert char A-Z to corresponding int.

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to convert A char from an array (2nd and 3rd) slot to int value that correspond to eg. A = 1 , B= 2, etc. For A-Z.

I am thinking that the long way will be doing if(x.charAt(i) == 'a'){ int z = 1; } for the whole A - Z which i think it is a very practical method. Is there any method that can do the same thing with a shorter code?

```
public static void computeCheckDigit(String x){
char [] arr = new char[x.length()];

for(int i=0; i<x.length();i++){
    arr[i] = x.charAt(i);
}


}
```

Comment: If `'A' == 1`, what does `'a'` equal?

Comment: If you're working with ASCII characters, you could do something like `(int)Character.toUpperCase('A') - 64` which will = `1` (or `(int)Character.toUpperCase(x.charAt(i)) - 64`)

Comment: The string will be something like mixture of char and int. I will need to convert only 2nd and 3rd letter to int as calculation will be needed after that. Will add in ignorecase after.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. I used int sec = (int)Character.toUpperCase(x.charAt(1)) - 64;

Comment: @LRZJohn My answer below solves your problem or you want something else?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(x.charAt(i)) - 'a' + 1;
```

You have to use int Array instead char Array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "AbC";
    int[] arr = new int[x.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(x.charAt(i)) - 'a' + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to be case agnostic, you might want to uppercase or lowercase the string first, but you'd want to be locale-aware:

```
// If you don't state a locale, and you are in Turkey,
// weird things can happen. Turkish has the İ character.
// Using lower case instead could lead to the ı character instead.
final String xu = x.toUpperCase(Locale.US);
for (int i = 0; i < xu.length(); ++i) {
    arr[i] = xu.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
}
```

An alternative loop would use:

```
// Casing not necessary.
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
    // One character
    String letter = x.substr(i, i+1);
    // A is 10 in base 11 and higher.  Z is 35 in base 36.
    // Subtract 9 to have A-Z be 1-26.
    arr[i] = Integer.valueOf(letter, 36) - 9;
}
```

Comment: It's applied paranoia.  I edited my answer to point out that you don't need to change the case in my second alternative.